# cout changes variable from nan to zero?

Tags: nan, cout

I have a problem that is quite curious. In the following I have a small cutout of my code. The program seems to create without any reason nan outputs and therefore it does not work. After 58 loops the output of the return value res_force_vector becomes nan (I have no idea why...).
However, if I want to know the vector loc_force_vec the code seems to work fine and the output vector res_force_vec is not nan any more????
Does cout change something in the code? How could I fix this problem?

```
....
// Material data of linear material
double E = elements_info(i,2);
double d = elements_info(i,3);
double nue = elements_info(i,4);
//calculate inner restoring force vector
element_array[i].load_data(x_coor,y_coor,E,nue,d);
VectorXd loc_force_vec =  element_array[i].create_force_lin(disp_elem,save_params,timestep_counter);
cout << "local force of element: " << i << endl; 
cout << loc_force_vec << endl;        /////////// this line
//write local into global force vector
    for (int k=0;k<dof_vec.rows();k++){
  dof = dof_vec(k);
  if (dof!=0){
    res_force_vec(dof-1) += loc_force_vec(k);
  }
}
cout << "norm of internal force of element: " << i << endl;
cout << res_force_vec.norm() << endl;
cin.get();
}
return res_force_vec;
....
```

I hope this problem is not unique...

Thanks in advance
Franz

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, all outputs res_force_vec should be zero vectors. Actually they are, but after 58 loops it changes to nan and if I want to see the reasons by checking all variables by cout it appears that res_force_vec is not nan any more. Perhaps loc_force_vector is also nan but when I print it with cout it changes to the correct value zero????
Sorry guys I am kind of desperate...